# Arc Map Generated KML needs an Expiration set for distribution

Tags: google-apps-script, kml, arcmap

I am looking to insert an Expiration into the KML's that I produce so when I send them out to my customers they expire after a certain date and time.. ie they come back and grab the latest and greatest KMLS that are published ... say on SharePoint or something. Can this be done with this some scripting? Can this scripting set an expiration inside the KML after it is created? or does anyone know if a software that can set a KMLs Expiration? so it is no longer usable after a certain time from the creation point?

I cannot find anything that will work.

Comment: Have you read [Expiration](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/expiration)?

Comment: I have, the problem I have is how to actually deploy that to a KML, like... I cannot seem to find a video to anything that says, here is the codes, and here is how to use them. I am pretty sure the python one will work for me, but not sure how to deploy it to my Companys KML's

Comment: In "Example 2", `python` is a red-herring. The "result" is the important thing, not how it was calculated - this example is for in-house use; no-one expects you to distribute a python script. In the example, the first file `KML NetworkLink` contains `<refreshMode>`. The second file (a child file) sets an "expires" for `<expires></expires>`. Look at the [Documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference) on `<refreshMode>` - If a fetched file has a **NetworkLinkControl**, the **<expires>** time takes precedence.

Comment: Read [Cache expiration with kml files and google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15469292/1330560). Both answers have some value, but there's a comment referencing two (2) KML files in pastebin. One of these has an example of the `expires` element: `<NetworkLinkControl><expires>2013-04-05T05:58:17Z</expires></NetworkLinkControl>`. I am NOT an expert (at all), but this pastebin file is consistent with Example#2. And _you_ manually insert the expiry date. On a tangent, this second file also seems to include the changes to Placemark coordinates which are, I think, the key map changes.

Comment: but how do you get this into the KML? I guess is what I am asking?

Comment: `but how do you get this into the KML?` You cited `arcmap` . Perhaps you would explain how you currently create and distribute KML files to clients.